# How to satisfy this pattern comparison in vim script?

Tags: vim, pattern-matching

I came across the following string comparison in a vim script.

```
echo my_test_var =~ '\\\@<!`.*\\\@<!`'
```

I am trying to figure out, what should be the value of `my_test_var` so that the comparison returns `1`.

Comment: It matches an unescaped backtick, then any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last unescaped backtick. Something like `\`some \\`text\\` here\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vim, the `\@<!` is a **negative lookbehind** construct that fails any match if it is preceded with the lookbehind pattern. Thus, the whole expression will match a string like

```
`some \`text\` here`
```

as

- `` \\\@<!` `` - match a backtick that is not immediately preceded with a backslash
- `.*` - matches 0+ characters, as many as possible
- `` \\\@<!` `` - match a backtick that is not immediately preceded with a backslash